# Overwriting route function (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I was trying to overwrite the route function Backbone.Router, here are my codes:

**router.js**

```
(function($, Backbone, _, app){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home'
        },
        initialize: function (options) {
            Backbone.history.start();
        },
        route: function (route, name, callback) {
             var router = this;
             if (!callback) callback = router[name];
             var f = function() {
                 console.log("route before", route);
                 callback.apply(router, arguments);
                 console.log("route after", route);
             }
             return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(router, route, name, f);
        }
    });
    app.router = AppRouter;
})(jQuery, Backbone, _, app);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = (function($){
    var config = $('#config'),
        app = JSON.parse(config.text());
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var router = new app.router();
    });
    return app;
})(jQuery);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/underscore.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/backbone.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.min.js"></script>


    <!--App js-->
        <script id="config" type="text/json">
            {
                "models": {},
                "collections": {},
                "views": {},
                "router": null,
                "apiRoot": "{% url 'api-root' %}",
                "apiLogin": "{% url 'api-token' %}"
            }
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'app-js/app.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'app-js/models.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'app-js/views.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'app-js/router.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, 'before' and 'after' was not printed on console.

I was following the code on http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/EdLzh/

And before and after was printed on the console.

And I also tried replacing the calling of the parent's 'route',

```
Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(router, route, name, f);
```

with

```
AppRouter.__super__.route.apply(router, [route, name, callback]);
```

But the function f is still not called.

I also tried replacing the same statement with

```
Backbone.Router.prototype.route.apply(router, [route, name, f]);
```

and also

```
Backbone.Router.prototype.route.apply(this, [route, name, f]);
```

and also

```
Backbone.Router.prototype.route.callback(this, route, name, f);
```

But the function f is still not called in the browser's console.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First, your router doesn't set a `home` callback but the override assumes that this callback exists and ends with an error when it is executed.

Try to add a safeguard, for example

```
route: function (route, name, callback) {
     var router = this;
     if (!callback) callback = router[name];

     // adds a default function that will intercept the missing callbacks
     if (!callback) {
        callback = function() {
            console.log('Route ' + name + '  not defined');
        }
     }

     var f = function() {
         console.log("route before", route);
         callback.apply(router, arguments);
         console.log("route after", route);
     }
     return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(router, route, name, f);
}
```

A demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/a78n9rj1/2/

And second, note that the routes must be defined via the `routes` hash or via [`Router.route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) for something to happen in that function, it won't catch all the hash changes.